# PostgreSQL react-native setup

Tags: postgresql, react-native

I'm having issues getting PostgreSQL to run on my local machine with react-native.  I work primarily as a database developer so it's possible I'm missing something, but in my opinion this is something that should be well documented.

I run the following commands to create a react native project (npm v 4.6.1)

```
npm install -g expo cli
expo init needhelp
cd needhelp
```

then I paste in my app.js file and it runs fine.  This is my `app.js` file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

//const { Client } = require('pg')
//const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style = {{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center',}}>
                <Text>Hello World!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I try and include pg in any way I get errors.  The first error I get is "unable to resolve module pg."  Then after I run `npm install pg`, I get

> [22:32:20] The package at "node_modules\pg\lib\index.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "util". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo
>   [22:32:20] Failed building JavaScript bundle.

Then after installing this I get:

> [22:34:03] The package at "node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "net". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo
>   [22:34:03] Failed building JavaScript bundle.
>   Building JavaScript bundle [===================================================================================== ] 9>

Then

> [2:36:57] The package at "node_modules\pg\lib\client.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "events". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo
>   [22:36:57] Failed building JavaScript bundle.

then

> [00:38:48] The package at "node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "tls". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo
>   [22:38:48] Failed building JavaScript bundle.

Then finally, the error that dooms me:

> metro bundler has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details.

Comment: React native does not run nodejs therefore native node libraries like pg does not work with it out of the box. You might need to use a react native version of the database connector -if there is any- or use a web service or sort as a communication middleware with the database.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Thanks for helping me!  Do you have any suggestions on what database I can use that scales well and is sql?

Comment: @mattsmith "in my opinion this is something that should be well documented." --agreed 100%